# Multiple Activities App Quit

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app which consisits of 25 Activities. I have Recently Added a Quit Button to it to quit the app but it doesnot works at all.

i have tried to fininsh() that activity but that takes me to previous activity. 
i have even tried to make my own backstack but that shows all activities when quiting the app which were present in backstack showing them for a fraction of second before quiting the app.
Have even read this complete article but nothing seems to help

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: What's your app requirement .. Do you also need to get back if needed ?

Comment: Yes if user presses back it should take to previous activity that is working fine i have provided proper back navigation but my app is not quiting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a hack to solve your problem. but i have just made an app and tested my code and it is working fine.

You will need to create a new activity called QuitActivity or whatever you want to name it and when you want to finish your app or quit your app you will have to start that activity via using this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuitActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
this.finish();
```

then this is my code for quit activity that does nothing but closes it self after clearing the backstack so your app will quit.

```
public class QuitActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. over button click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentClass.this, HomeClass.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement one Custom BroadCastReceiver and register it in each activity.When you tap on the Quit button sendBroadcast to that particular custom intent. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

try type only System.exit(0);

or create static boolean needToExit;

set needToExit = true;

in place where you call

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

in all other activity overwrite onresume

```
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
if (MySettingsClass.needToExit){
finish();
System.exit(0);
return;
}

//your other code;
}
```